# Leaflet issues angular woes in showing and hiding? Want to get rid of $timeout

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I have a leaflet being created with L.map('mapelement') being called. The issue is that if I click a button that "hides" the leaflet map, then click the button again to show, the leaflet map does not show up. However, when I put in a setTimeout within the link function before the map gets created and set it to 2 seconds, then the map shows every time (though I have to wait 2 seconds). Is there a better alternative to using $timeout in my custom "leaflet-map" directive to show and hide?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: How about using $timeout(func,0); It will just add your map show task to last of execution queue.

Comment: So I wrapped the entire contents within the link of the directive in a "start" function where I have:                 $timeout(function() {
                    $timeout(start, 0);
                });. Seems a bit wonky to have to force wait. Am hoping there is some "viewdidload" or some event i could use.

Comment: Not to mention, it does not work unless I set the $timeout to be 1000 ms.

Comment: When you show the map again (and it fails), is the map element there? Is it gray/blank? Wrong size? Any console errors? Problems with your custom directive? Please post some code so others can test, it's hard to guess

Answer (score 1):

Would CSS help you ?

Create one map in a visible div

```
visibility: visible
```

Create the second map in a hidden div

```
visibility: hidden
```

Position both your div in the same position

```
position: absolute
```

When you want to toggle just change the visibility of your divs

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/voTjyMLKTxUC183nf8ML?p=preview
(Sorry it's not angular)

Answer (score 1):

I created a naive example of a leaflet-map directive without seeing any of your code and am toggling the display of the map through ng-show. It works without any $timeout. It's hard to diagnose where your problems are stemming from without seeing any code or knowing how you are trying to toggle the map's display.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

.directive('leafletMap', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      mapOptions: '&'
    },
    template: '<div><button ng-click="toggleShow()">Toggle Map</button><div class="demo-map" ng-show="isShown"></div></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // Find element to bind to map
      var mapElem = elem.children().find('div')[0],
        // get map options from isolate scope
        mapOptions = scope.mapOptions();

      // State of hide/show
      scope.isShown = true;

      // Create Map.
      var map = L.map(mapElem, mapOptions);

      // Just taken from leaflet example
      L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
          '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
          'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
      }).addTo(map);

      // method to toggle the shown/hidden state of map
      scope.toggleShow = function() {
        scope.isShown = !scope.isShown;
      };

      // cleanup on element destroy
      elem.on('$destroy', function() {
        map.remove();
      });
    }
  };
})

.controller('DemoController', function() {
  this.mapOptions = {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
  };


});
```

```css
.demo-map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController as ctrl">
  <leaflet-map map-options="ctrl.mapOptions"></leaflet-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem occurs when I have 2 leaflet maps and I want to switch the display of one vs the other. Each with a different ID.

Comment: The id of the element shouldn't matter if you are using directive with isolate scope. Code above works with a map directly through element reference. I could modify the above code to have two leaflet maps that is driven off outside variable, but at this point I'm simply guessing because I still haven't seen what you are trying to do.